# Javascript + PHP timed actions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my goal:
Create some JavaScript action (some function call) that will be timed perfectly between two different clients.

Explanation:
I want a function to be called exactly on the same millisecond on two different browsers/computers no matter when the client accessed the web page.

I thought about creating a time base using the server time but im not sure this will work.

Comment: You do need to rely on the server time for that (have you checked out the `time()`-function?). And in order to not rely on the client requesting the page EXACTLY when the time has been reached, you do need to use some client-sided script to keep track of it. You can simply echo the JS-script using PHP, and from there set the correct timer (check out the JS-timeout functions). Although realize that it's not really an accurate idea... Relying timing on client-side parsed code isn't really. For instance, it can be deactivated, and manipulated (unlike PHP, which is parsed on the server).

Comment: Actually you can't rely on the server time because the transit time from the server to the two clients will almost always vary. So if you plan to time it down to the ms, then you're going to need to send a "start time" back to both clients with sufficient delay that you can confirm they've both received it, then let them both start at the same time (localized to their timezone of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using something Node.JS or APE (Ajax Push Engine) to achieve this.

Comment: thx, going over it now

Answer (score -1):

so you want to do like this scenario: user come visit your webpage and he has to wait few seconds that page is shown?

This is useless to do in my opinion, unless you want to flood server with tons of requests..

Comment: I think you misunderstood him... And really, this isn't much of an answer to his question, merely your own opinion. I advice you to use comments.

Comment: you cannot add comment if you have reputation < 50 .

Comment: True, but your answer is still not an answer. Thus, it doesn't belong as an answer.

Comment: no, to make it a simple as possible - if i have an image slider on my web page. user 1 and user 2 will see the exact slide and the slide event will be fired on the same time for both